# Verilog Assertion

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, assertion

everyone.
I am relatively new to Verilog and I am working on a build-in-self-test module.
I am trying to use 'assertion' to see if the logic is reading correctly,
I was wondering, if I can assert a PIN instead of signal.

For example, if I have a pin called MEM_READ

then during instantiation, instead of defining the pin explicitly as .MEM_READ(mem_read)

I am trying to use the pin .MEM_READ itself.

Thanks

Comment: The question might be easier to understand with a code example. What is the difference between a pin and a signal? What error did you get when you tried to use the pin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always refer to any entity in the design by its hierarchical name. For example, say I have the following simple code:

```
module top;

  logic a, b;

  modit ma(.in(a),
           .out(b)),
        mb(.in(b),
           .out(a));

endmodule

module modit(input logic in, output logic out);

  assign out = ~in;

endmodule
```

If I want to refer to the `in` port of the `mb` module from anywhere in the design, I can simply use `$root.mb.in` or if I want to refer to it from the top module, I can use `mb.in`

Its important to realize that the `in` port is really just a signal in the `modit` module, so I can thus refer to any signal using similar hierarchical names.